# Why attributes in dispatch don't come in actions (vuex)?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a problem with sending data from vue to vuex.
When I am try send dates to vuex via 'let' - axios don't see these dates.
But when I am try input dates in axios request - ok, and I can see response.
Why it could be?
[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't run and debug pictures of code. Please create a *runnable* [mcve] if you need help debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple params to Vuex actions you need to wrap them in an object, e.g.

`loadIncomings(context, { clubId, dateFrom, dateTo })`

Vuex considers the first param as the context and the second as the payload. That's why your `clubId` gets passed but all other params are discarded.